# intellij spring boot run cannot load application.yml automatically

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

[my application.yml locate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dN84L.png)

[my application.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SiPpO.png)

[spring boot run server port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElVMU.png)

[Intellij spring boot run configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9DA5.png)

Hi.
My project is Intellij spring boot 1.5.7 Gradle Project
When Intellij spring boot run cannot load application.yml automatically.
but gradle bootRun is very well run&load.
Please suggestion me.

Comment: Remove your IntelliJ run configuration. Go to SaySaySayApplication main method and run it.

Comment: Please, better post your images directly in the question and not in a third part service. Also try to post the code and logs as text, not as an image. There's a code block mode in the SO editor.

Comment: module directory/out/production folder in cannot created resources folder ..

Answer (score 0):

You should specify profile configuration. From your application.yml, you have multiple configuration separated by "---", this is used for multiple profile configuration for different spring profile. Try removing "---" and specify profile as following :[image]

Multiple configuration is used when you have different configuration for different profile, as following:
[image]